# R programming latin1 encoding errors when reading MS Word docs

Tags: r, ms-word, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I am reading in several MS Word documents into a function that extracts certain sections of the text to R in order to put into an excel output, but my latin1 encoding portions are wrong. I have tried multiple iterations of this code to see if it could remove some of the special characters but no luck. This is the original section of the code.

There is an issue in the 4th and 5th gsub() portion of the script that has two "" next to each other, this came in from the initial script but I am not sure exactly how they got this to work.

```
# remove latin1 encoding errors
       Encoding(title) <- "latin1"
                              title <- gsub("Ã¢Â???Â", "\"", title)
                              title <- gsub("Ã¢Â???Âo", "\"", title)
                              title <- gsub("â???T", "'", title)
                              title <- gsub("â???o", "'", title)
                              title <- gsub("â???"", "-", title)
                              title <- gsub("â???"", "-", title)
                              title <- gsub("â???'", "-", title)
                              title <- gsub("â???", "-", title)
                              title <- gsub("Â", " ", title)
                              title <- gsub("Ì¶", "-", title)                                                                
       title_output <- append(title_output, title)
```

This is my latest format with another field "descriptions" that I have used, which has been the closest to how I want the text read in.

```
 # remove latin1 encoding errors          
       Encoding(description) <- "latin1"
          description <- gsub("Ã¢Â???Â", "\"", description)
          description <- gsub("Ã¢Â???Âo", "\"", description)
          description <- gsub("â???T", "'", description)
          description <- gsub("â???o", "'", description)
          description <- gsub("â???", "-", description)
          description <- gsub("â???", "-", description)
          description <- gsub("â???'", "-", description)
          description <- gsub("â???", "-", description)
          description <- gsub("Â", " ", description)
          description <- gsub("Ì¶", "-", description)

          description_output <- append(description_output, description)
```

My end result output looks like this:

o-m-m-e-r-c-i-a-l- -a-n-d- -i-n-d-u-s-t-r-i-a-l- -d-e-v-e-l-o-p-m-e-n-t-,- -a-n-d- -c-r-e-a-t-e- -o-p-p-o-r-t-u-n-i-t-i-e-s- -f-o-r- -j-o-b- -c-r-e-a-t-i-o-n- -i-n- -t-h-e- -r-e-g-i-o-n-.- a-r-e- -a-w-a-r-d-e-d- -t-h-r-o-u-g-h- -a- -c-o-m-p-e-t-i-t-i-v-e- -p-r-o-c-e-s-s- -b-a-s-e-d- -u-p-o-n- -t-h-e- -a-p-p-l-i-c-a-t-i-o-n-â-€-™-s- -m-e-r-i-t-,- -t-h-e- -a-p-p-l-i-c-a-n-t-â-€-™-s- -e-l-i-g-i-b-i-l-i-t-y-,- -a-n-d- -t-h-e- -a-v-a-i-l-a-b-i-l-i-t-y- -o-f- -f-u-n-d-s-.- - -M-o-r-e- -i-n-f-o-r-m-a-t-i-o-n- -o-n- -â-€-™-s- -g-r-a-n-t- -p-r-o-c-e-s-s- -a-n-d- -i-n-v-e-s-t-m-e-n-t- -p-r-o-c-e-s-s- -c-a-n- -b-e- -f-o-u

My goal is to remove the "-" and the special characters.

Comment: Try using `gsub("-", "", description_output)`.  For special characters, you could do the same but with the `[[:print:]]` regular expression.  Source: https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf

Comment: @Punintended I took out the dashes from the replacement part of the gsub() but I don't follow how you would use the [[:print:]] in this portion of the code. However, taking out the dashes helped out tremendously, thank you.

Comment: The `[[:print:]]` regex selects alpha-numerics, punctuation and spaces, so you could gsub based on that.  Alternatively, it looks like your apostrophes are consistently misread (except for the "More information on ?? grant process"), so you could gsub that particular string